# C#: How to find tags with regex and collect a List<string>

Tags: c#, regex, list, split

I have a text string like this:

```
<dt>
  <span>
    <tag:text name="fee" />
  </span>
</dt>
...
<tag:text name="amount" />
```

what I want is to find all tags of type

```
<tag:text
```

and then collect a List with the values from the name element:

```
"fee"
"amount"
```

Comment: This *looks* like it's XML... don't try to parse XML with regular expressions. If it's *not* actually XML, can you convert it to XML?

Comment: [See this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) for why using regex to parse xml/html/etc like that makes children weep the blood of virgins...

Comment: @chown - Totally forgot about that post, that made my day.

Comment: yes Jon you're right it looks like XML. But I have no need to parse the entire document, only to find tag:text elements and replace them with meaningful data.

it is for an editor where the user edit the "looks like XML-document" and must be able to see the result, therefore I can not be guaranteed that the document is valid at all times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?<=tag:text name=").*(?=")
```

test with grep:

```
kent$  echo '<dt>
      <span>
        <tag:text name="fee" />
      </span>
    </dt>
    ...
    <tag:text name="amount" />   '|grep -Po '(?<=tag:text name=").*(?=")' 

    fee
    amount
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the regex you *(EDIT: probably don't)* want, just make sure to turn off case sensitivity:

```
<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>
```

Then just use the `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` class to perform the regex operation:

```
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(str, @"<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

See here for more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b49yw9s8.aspx

Note: You may need to tweak the regex to work with the colons in your text.

Note #2: As mentioned above, if this is XML then you should parse it using the appropriate XML classes from the `System.Xml` namespace.

Comment: If the “text” in question is really XML, this won't handle properly many situations that are perfectly legal XML, like comments, CDATA sections, tag names with with underscores or other characters, empty elements and, most importantly, nested tags, like: `<tag><tag></tag></tag>`.

Comment: @svick - My bad, when I read the regex I thought the backreference was handling nested tags, but it wasn't.